# Sort multi-dimensional array with decimal values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array as such:

```
[0] => Array (
  [id] => 17 
  [score] => 9.37272727273
)
[1] => Array (
  [id] => 1 
  [score] => 9.19791666667
) 
[2] => Array (
  [id] => 2
  [score] => 9.23333333333
)
```

How do I sort this array by score, in descending order?

I have tried:

```
usort($match_scores, 'sortByScore');

function sortByScore($a, $b) {
    return $b['score'] - $a['score'];
}
```

Although it does seem to *mostly* sort the array, the result isn't always accurate! It seems like some values still slip through, maybe because of the decimals? Score is a `float`

Comment: `return $b['score'] > $a['score'] ? 1 : -1;`?

Comment: Thank you very much. That works indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = array(
    array('id' => 2, 'score' => 4.6),
    array('id' => 5, 'score' => 1.7),
    array('id' => 6, 'score' => 3.7),
);

usort($arr, 'sort_by_score');

function sort_by_score($a, $b) {
    return $b['score'] > $a['score'] ? 1 : -1;
}

var_dump($arr);
```